# Update table procedure through pl sql using double loop

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Assuming that I have only one table :
members_tbl which columns are :SN, FN, DB, IDDBL,FLAG, DBLCRIT I need to update the table if some conditions are OK with this algorithm :

```
   id_dup := 1;
FOR (i in 1 to Nrow(members_tbl)) THEN
{
FOR (j in (i+1) to Nrow(members_tbl)) THEN
{
IF(members_tbl(i).iddbl IS NULL) THEN
members_tbl(i).iddbl := id_dup
IF (((members_tbl(i).DBIRTH ==members_tbl(j).DBIRTH) AND
    (UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(members_tbl(i).SNAME,members_tbl(j).SNAME) > 80) AND
  (UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(members_tbl(i).FNAME,members_tbl(j).FNAME) > 80)) 
AND (members_tbl(j).iddbl IS NULL)) THEN
{
   members_tbl(j).iddbl := id_dup;
   members_tbl(i).flag := 1;
   members_tbl(j).flag := 1;
   members_tbl(i).dblcrit:= 1;
   members_tbl(j).dblcrit:= 1;
}

}
   id_dup := id_dup + 1;
}
```

Here is a test case :

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBERS_TBL
  (
    IDM     NUMBER(9) NOT NULL ,
    SNAME   VARCHAR2(20) ,
    FNAME   VARCHAR2(20) ,
    DBIRTH  VARCHAR2(15) ,
    IDDBL   NUMBER(10) ,
    FLAG    SMALLINT ,
    DBLCRIT SMALLINT
  );
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (125,'BOLOREY','JEANNE','11/05/1955',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (126,'BOLLOREY','JEANNE','11/05/1955',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (153,'BALORE','GIANNE','11/05/1955',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (223,'ABOLLOREYY','JEANNE','11/05/1955',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (225,'FIABLE','MARINE','25/04/1963',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (228,'FAIBLE','MARYANE','25/04/1963',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (230,'FAIBLE','MARINE','25/04/1963',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (235,'LIPARK','JACQLINE','20/12/1939',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (236,'ILIPARC','JACQUELYNE','20/12/1939',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (237,'LIPARC','JACQUELHINE','20/12/1939',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (240,'RINTET','MALIKA','07/08/1954',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (241,'GRISION','RAUGER','26/10/1931',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (242,'GRISION','ROGER','26/10/1931',NULL,NULL,NULL);
Insert into members_tbl (IDM,SNAME,FNAME,DBIRTH,IDDBL,FLAG,DBLCRIT) values (245,'GRESION','RAUJER','26/10/1931',NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

to be more comprensive, i do change columns SN in SNAME, FN in FNAME and DB in DBIRTH

Is there a way to write this algorithm in a pl/sql procedure ?
I'm relatively new to PL/SQL and i've never written a stored procedure.

Comment: I doubt you need the loops. How does `NumberOfrow()` determine the row number?

Comment: I've tried this algorithm on another language such like R it work but on  large data I'd like to exploit the server performance to run it directly on it. Any suggstion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work. You'll need to figure out how it determines which row is "higher" and thus the duplicate.

```
update members_tbl
set iddbl = 1
where iddbl is null and exists (
    select 1
    from members_tbl m2
    where
            m2.DB = members_tbl.DB
        and UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(members_tbl.FN, m2.FN) > 80
        and UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(members_tbl.SN, m2.SN) > 80
        and NumberOfRow(m2) < NumberOfRow(members_tbl) /* ??? */

);

update members_tbl
set flag = 1, dblcrit = 1;
```

Comment: This won't work because I have to find potential duplicates by using the jaro_winkler similarity on name et Surname so I use to edit my post to better clarify it.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of changing to use jaro_winkler rather than strict equality?

Comment: Thx for the reply; Running this query I have this error :
Erreur SQL : 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis" at the 5th line; If I tried to remove the "as" statement (is it right ?), I have another error I have another error at line 12th :
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended", everything seems look good but i don't know what it's going wrong. \n
Ps: And how about the iddbl increment ?

Comment: Yes, you're right about `as`. And I think the other problem was semicolons. You won't need a counter(s) if you take away the loop.

Comment: Now I have this error : 
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" : "NUMBEROFROW"  
I note the presence of 2 comma ";" even removing the first it doesn't work.

Comment: I put questions marks in my answer because you're going to have to determine which row is the duplicate. The one with a later timestamp? The one with a higher id number? Is NumberOfRow/NRow an Oracle function?

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, as suggested by @shawnt00, it's a duplicate detection based on the approximation of character strings through Jaro Winkler's functio; Consequently, there is no need of count (no need of flag, dblcrit, iddbl), but simply a left outer join :

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT m.IDM,
       m2.IDM AS dups_key
FROM members_tbl m
LEFT OUTER JOIN members_tbl m2
ON ( m.IDM != m2.IDM
      AND m.DBIRTH = m2.DBIRTH
      AND utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(m.SNAME,m2.SNAME) > 80
      AND utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(m.FNAME,m2.FNAME) > 80 )
    )
Where dups_key IS NOT NULL;
```

And from that, I've extracted other informations that I needed if I'd have used the counters previously mentioned; so at the following link, here are others data extracted from the first query above: [this link.](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3774735?start=0&tstart=0)